# Is this a correct use of Android Fragments and NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Although I have been working with Android for years, this is my first time using `Fragments` in a real life project. So I am a bit confused :-P

This app has a `NavigationDrawer` with 4 main sections. I am using just one main `Activity` with a `Layout` that has a content `View` which I replace with `Fragments`. When an option in the `NavigationDrawer` is selected, I instantiate a `Fragment` and put it in that content `View`. I am doing something like this:

```
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

public static int drawerSelectedOption = 0;
private void selectItem(int position) {
    drawerSelectedOption = position;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new StoresFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            //promos
        case 2:
            fragment = new TransactionsFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Settings();
            break;
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mSectionTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

More `Fragments` are pushed from within each one of the main `NavigationDrawer` `Fragments`. So each one of the main 'screens' have several sub screens inside like shown below.

```
Drawer __ Fragment 1.0  -- Fragment 1.1 -- Fragment 1.2
      |__ Fragment 2.0  -- Fragment 2.1 -- Fragment 2.2
```

I am pushing those inner `Fragments` from the previous `Fragment` `ActionBar` menus like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        OrderCreateFragment fragment = new OrderCreateFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

I am facing several problems and that's why I am looking for some advice about this approach:

1. I don't even know how to properly manage the `ActionBar` menu items. Every `Fragment` has its own menus and sometimes they are stuck in the bar (ie. if switching `Fragments` by tapping on the `NavigationDrawer` instead of going back with the Android back key)
2. `StackBack` should be popped completely when selecting one of the `NavigationDrawer` options. I suspect my `ActionBar` messy items are related to this because the `Fragments` are kept in the stack somehow.

So, can anyone please kindly advice whether is this a proper approach and how to address the issues with the `StackBack` and the `ActionBar`?

**UPDATE**:
Looks like clearing the whole stack on the selectItem method solved the 2 main issues. Though I am still interested in listening opinions about this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I reckon best way depends on the application needs.  Considering 2 scenarios

A- App has requirement for navigationdrawer & multiple activities with nested/deep navigation .
   Then best approach is to have a base activity which has a framelayout and  navigationdrawer. All activities extends/inherits from this base Activity.
And for each activity inflate the respective layout and add to framelayout container of baseActivity programmatically.
 The back stack navigation is easier.

B - App has requirement for navigationdrawer & only single tier navigation.
  Then one can use the concept of dynamically adding and replacing the fragments on a single Activity which has navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

This is the tutorial I used to learn navigation drawers. Found it pretty useful. It walks through process of setting up drawer, linking it to icons, and uploading fragments to the page.

Comment: This is the same tutorial I actually followed. While it works well for the simple example they show, I think it is a very wrong approach for bigger projects (i.e. having 1 activity and all the fragments being added/replaced from there, and having several levels in each of the navigation drawer options). I would never follow that example again, you can't imagine how many problems and hacky workarounds I needed to do in order to make the app work properly :-(